# Unexpected interpolation on @import path

Tags: css, import, sass, path, interpolation

Simple question - I have a long import path and want to import selected modules:

```
$mdbpro_path: '../../../../node_modules/mdbootstrap-pro/';

// Bootstrap
@import "#{$mdbpro_path}core/bootstrap/functions";
@import "#{$mdbpro_path}core/bootstrap/variables";
@import "#{$mdbpro_path}core/bootstrap/rfs";
...
```

I have also tried:

```
@import $mdbpro_path + "core/bootstrap/functions";
```

I just want to concat the string which is being imported. But it all causes errors?

Comment: Please stop prefixing all your question titles with what amounts to a tag. Use the tags for that.

Comment: @j08691 Seemed like common practice to me in earlier times? I will try to remember.